# Is there a tool that will make rapid web requests?

Tags: testing, browser, webrequest

I'm trying to test some software that analyzes web requests from browsers and other sources. Is there a tool that will rapidly and repeatedly make requests to various urls? These urls could be random, from a list, or as they are found on the pages that are requested. It makes little difference to me.

Is there such at tool? Perhaps a browser plugin? Or should I just write something myself?

Answer (score 1):

Try [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> curl is a tool to transfer data from
>   or to a server, using one of the
>   supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP,
>   FTPS, GOPHER, **HTTP**, **HTTPS**, IMAP,
>   IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP,
>   RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET
>   and TFTP). The command is designed to
>   work without user interaction.

Sample:

Get the main page from Netscape's web-server:

```
    curl http://www.netscape.com/
```

More in the [manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html).

Comment: That could work, but I don't see anything in the documentation on how to make a large amount of multiple requests.

Comment: If it's not built-in, you could write a batch file or a C++ program to call cURL as needed!

Comment: I might as well do it all within the program then, making web requests is easy enough in .Net. Thanks anyway.